# Eclipse, use template to surround all the lines in the selection with something

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

I'm using eclipse for java development.
I have something like this:

```
text
text
text
text
```

and I want to change it in something like this:

```
(some text)text(some text)
(some text)text(some text)
(some text)text(some text)
(some text)text(some text)
```

I can easly do that using templates on a single row, but there is a way to do the same thing for all the rows, in one shot? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use block selection mode as the search key is same and has constant width.

> Keep the caret on start of first `text` word. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. Notice a long blinking caret. copy replace key word `(some text)` to clipboard. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste or just type the characters. Repeat this after keeping the caret at the end of the first `text` word.

Use Find and replace dialog and regular expressing to do it.

> Select the range of text then Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. Make sure in the **scope** group **selected lines** is selected. In **Find** text box enter `\b(text).*` in **Replace with** text box enter `(some text)$0(some text)`

Comment: mmm... this is not exactly what I had in mind. I just wish to know if there is a way to do this using templates, so I can do it with a shortcut.